# Solr Connection reset by peer

Tags: tomcat, solr, apache-zookeeper

I am using Solr for data indexing and search.
I have three zookeeper servers zk1,zk2,zk3 with port 2183,2184,8185 for that I am using three external tomcat tomcat1 tomcat2 tomcat3 with port 7070,8080,9090
It works perfectly.
But it gives error sometimes while searching like

```
    org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server xxx.xxx.x.xx/xxx.xxx.x.xx:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:384)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:68)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:355)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
```

If I shutdown and restart tomcat it again works perfectly for me.How can I resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

This is due to zookeeper max client connections property  or mis-configuration that result this error

Please check your /etc/zookeeper/conf => find => "maxClientCnxns = 20", comment it out and restart zookeeper.

**UPDATE:**
Also check this link http://marcin.cylke.com.pl/blog/2013/03/21/zookeeper-tips/

Thanks

Comment: Thank You Ghayel. I did it,It is not working.May I have any other solution

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the HBase 0.90.4 library, which comes with Nutch 2.x... Please check this https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/ErrorMessagesInNutch2#Nutch_2.1_.2B-_HBase_0.90.4_cluster_settings_-_WARN__zookeeper.ClientCnxn_-_Session_0x0_for_server_node1.xxxxxx.com.2Fxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2181.2C_unexpected_error.2C_closing_socket_connection_and_attempting_reconnect_java.io.IOException:_Connection_reset_by_peer